# clojure + clojurescript project structure best practices

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a simple project setup for ClojureScript.  I've been running a simple http server to test it out in the browser.  I'm at the point I want to add a backend.  Is this normally added in the same project file?

How do you package the assets like images, compiled ClojureScript files, and html files for the backend?

Comment: This question somehow reminded me bob martins talk on clean achitecture - https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Nsjsiz2A9mg

Comment: And having the database and the UI be plugins that depend on the business logic you write, not the other way around, reminded me of http://www.strandz.org/

Answer (score 4):

Check out various [Clojurescript templates](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki#project-templates) for patterns on how to organize projects. The backend is usually included in the same project, sometimes sharing parts of the code with the client/browser side. The assets are typically kept in a *resources* directory.